# PHP: Is it ok to replace \r\n with \n?

Tags: php, linefeed

I have a form with a textarea and a JS character counter. Yet the backend script claims that the strlen of the message is longer than the JS character counter claimed. The reason for this, I have discovered, is that the backend sees every newline character as `\r\n` which is two characters.

Can I simply have it do a `str_replace("\r\n","\n",$input)`? Or will this cause windows-users to see the string all on one line? Is there any reason why I should *not* do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a reasonable things to do...

Answer (score 1):

When storing it is acceptable to only use `\n`. You may choose to expand it when extracting later. Note that a `\r` in places other than just before a `\n` may hold other significance and so you should not just blindly remove all instances of it.